# Why does android emulator show black screen and its not string

Tags: android, emulation

Hi i am trying to start my emulator in eclipe but it's not starting. It shows logcat error as below...please help me....how to overcome this problem

```
09-11 19:13:13.020: I/Netd(622): Netd 1.0 starting
09-11 19:13:13.040: W/InterfaceController(622): Warning (dlopen failed: library"/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
09-11 19:13:13.260: I/SurfaceFlinger(623): SurfaceFlinger is starting
09-11 19:13:13.260: I/SurfaceFlinger(623): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
09-11 19:13:13.260: D/libEGL(623): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
09-11 19:13:13.300: D/libEGL(623): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-11 19:13:13.380: D/gralloc_goldfish(623): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-11 19:13:13.400: E/SurfaceFlinger(623): hwcomposer module not found
09-11 19:13:13.400: E/SurfaceFlinger(623): ERROR: failed to open framebuffer (No such  file or directory), aborting
09-11 19:13:13.400: A/libc(623): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000026f (code=-6), thread 623 (surfaceflinger)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "its not string" ?

Answer (score 0):

When booting the emulator from Eclipse, look at the Console tab, not the log tab. Console may show error messages. The Log tab only shows logcat, which are messages from Android itself

When you create a new emulator it warns you about assigning it too much RAM if you try anything above 768M the emulator may not start according to the error message at the bottom of the virtual device setup. Do try with 512M of RAM and see if it starts.

While creating emulator check the option "Use Host GPU" at the bottom

or try another API version

Comment: Thank you mr.sagar. but its not working still my emulator not open. ti open in APi level 16, but its not open in API level 19. how can i overcome it.